# Expecting method call from another method failing on test

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-test

Here is the function:

```
handleAddClinic() {
    HFSClinicTableSchema.headers.map((th) =>
        th.checked ? (th.checked = false) : th
    );
    this.popTableSchema = { ...HFSClinicTableSchema, rows: [] };
    this.openDialog(this.popupTemp);
}
openDialog(templateRef: TemplateRef<HTMLAllCollection>) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(templateRef);
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
        console.log(`Dialog result: ${result}`, HFSClinicTableSchema);
    });
}
```

Here is the spec I do :

```
fit('should reset the page', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(component, 'handleAddClinic');
    spyOn(component, 'openDialog');
    const addButton = fixture.debugElement.query(
        By.css('button#btnAddClinic')
    );
    addButton.nativeElement.click();
    tick();
    expect(component.handleAddClinic).toHaveBeenCalled(); //ok
    tick(5000);
    expect(component.openDialog).toHaveBeenCalled(); // error
}));
```

event though I given 5ms, my testing is failing at:

`tick(5000); expect(component.openDialog).toHaveBeenCalled();`

error:

```
 Error: Expected spy openDialog to have been called.
        at <Jasmine>
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: `spyOn(component, 'handleAddClinic').and.callThrough();`?

Comment: @yurzui - no same error. any other approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You do not need fakeAsync and tick in this scenario
- When you spy on a method the code in that method does not get called unless you use callThrough

```js
fit('should reset the page', () => {
  spyOn(component, 'handleAddClinic').and.callThrough();
  spyOn(component, 'openDialog');
  const addButton = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button#btnAddClinic'));
  addButton.nativeElement.click();

  expect(component.handleAddClinic).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(component.openDialog).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```